# How to pay taxes owed to IRS while in another country?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs, payment

I got a notice from the IRS that I need to pay them for taxes owed in 2012. How shall I pay the taxes online? I am currently in a foreign country.

I do not have Fedex close by. Is it accepted to email my friend scanned copies of the agreement form that the IRS mailed me (which will be signed and details filled in by me) so that he could Fedex from within the U.S. in order to reach the IRS in time? Essentially, are scanned copies accepted?

What would be the proof of payment? Would online receipt be good enough?

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't filing anything new (just accepting what the IRS says you owe) I think you can use the usual methods.

[IRS payment options](http://www.irs.gov/Payments)

DirectPay is essentially an electronic check.  They have options for doing it via credit or debit card for a small fee.

[Credit/Debt options](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Pay-Taxes-by-Credit-or-Debit-Card)

The IRS can be picky about some things, but when it comes to accepting money from you, they are pretty flexible and aren't going to hassle you for a signature.

Comment: Thank you. How about the agreement forms? I have only scanned copies. Do they need original? How about proof of payment?

Comment: They will provide a confirmation number, I believe, or other proof of payment when you pay online.  For agreement forms, I believe part of the payment process is an online form similar to the one you got and you "sign" it electronically as you go through the steps.  They don't need the paper they sent you.

Answer (score 1):

The IRS has offices in most large cities of foreign countries (basically anywhere Americans are likely to live). You might want to visit one of those offices and ask them what to do. It's possible that they might accept a check from you or forward your check to the United States,